# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on "EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled."

Tags: boot, uefi, asus, nomodeset

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.
Everything worked fine.
Two days ago my laptop would boot and get stuck on a black (dark purple) screen.
I fixed this by changing the boot parameters, replacing "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" like my google search suggested.
This worked.
Now for some reason today this fix would lead to a black screen reading

"EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled."

and nothing happening.

In BIOS I can't disable Secure Boot.
(The option is there but I can't "enter" that field so to speak.)

I now disabled fast boot and which led me to the GRUB command line and I could boot.
Then I restarted AGAIN and I got stuck on "EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled." again.
After enabling fast boot again, I could boot again.

machine ASUS UX303UA.202
What other information could I provide?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**nomodeset**

nomodeset only disables the video driver, and should only be used for troubleshooting. Update your video driver. Remember to change "nomodeset" back to "quiet splash".

**Secure Boot**

See the BIOS update.

**fast boot/hibernation**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

**BIOS**

ASUS UX303UA

You have BIOS version 202.

There's a newer BIOS that might fix your problem. Version 302, dated 6/5/2019, can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/UX303UA/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Note: Disable Secure Boot after updating the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Log in to recovery mode and then 'resume'
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub`, change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` so that: `"quiet splash"` becomes `"dis_ucode_ldr quiet splash"`
3. Run: `sudo update-grub`

Hopefully, this works for you.

Comment: You should really say what this does as it is rarely a good idea to use this parameter permanently. This parameter disables microcode (firmware) updates which normally happen on every boot. While microcode updates can very occasionally cause boot problems, they are important for security. See https://wiki.debian.org/Microcode. If someone tries this and finds it does not work, they should revert it. If it does work, they should try to revert it periodically to see if the bug got fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, I even didn't know it.

Comment: :) no worries. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!